# How do I make a containing div overflow hidden inside it's containing div

Tags: html, css, overflow

[image]

I'm trying to give this simple calculator app I'm making a 'light sheen', like what you'd see on a phone screen under light. What I've done is I've put a div for the light sheen inside the containing div which is the phone shape, but I can't make it so overflow is hidden for the light sheen div.

Hopefully the current code snippets help:

```html
<div class="phone-container">
        <div class="light-sheen"></div>
        <div class="upper-icons">
```

```css
.phone-container {
    height: 750px;
    width: 400px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 60px;
    border: 5px solid rgb(172, 172, 172);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.light-sheen {
    width: 900px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    transform: rotateZ(-35deg);
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `position: absolute;` on light-sheen,  it's not possible to hide the overflow part.

Make light-sheen `position: relative;` instead.

```
.light-sheen {
    width: 900px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    transform: rotateZ(-35deg);
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

Comment: Ohh got'cha that clears my confusion up, thanks!
One thing though, I used **scale** on *.phone-container* and it applied **overflow: hidden** on *.light-sheen*, despite it still using **position: absolute**?
I'm confused as to why it wasn't working when I didn't use the scale property on the containing div, but hey it works so I'm not complaining haha

Comment: Have a look at [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), I think this is what you are looking for.    

_If the property has a value different than none, a **stacking context** will be created. In that case, the element will act as a **containing block** for any position: fixed; or position: absolute; elements that it contains._